# php display wrong date

Tags: php, date, timezone, hosting

first, sorry if my English is not so good.
so, I have this problem in the date() function in my localhost and also in the free hosting, the function always display wrong time.
I use XAMPP

php.ini timezone in my localhost is : **Africa/Casablanca**  *my location*

on my localhost when I run this code

```
echo date("D, m/d/Y H:i:s a T e");
```

It gives this out put : **Mon, 09/14/2015 00:24:36 am WEST Africa/Casablanca**
when I should get **Mon, 09/13/2015 23:24:36 pm GMT GMT**
1 hour of difference

so, when I add this code in my script nothing change `date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Casablanca');`
But when I replace **Africa/Casablanca** by **GMT**
It display the correct time like this **Mon, 09/13/2015 23:24:36 am GMT GMT**

in the free hosting it's not the same the previous code display this out put
**Sun, 09/13/2015 18:24:39 pm EDT America/New_York**

and with **date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Casablanca');** the time is  correct

**Mon, 09/13/2015 23:24:36 am WEST Africa/Casablanca**

but with **date_default_timezone_set('GMT');**  again one hour of difference
**Sun, 09/13/2015 22:58:59 pm GMT GMT**

Does any one have a solution.
thanks, and have a good day

Comment: It sounds like the time might incorrect on the server. Can you try this on both servers? They should match for sure: `echo gmdate('D, m/d/Y H:i:s a T e');`

Comment: in the localhost the time is correct ** 00:34** , but in the hosting is gives one hour of difference **23:34**

Comment: That confirms it then, I would pass this information to your host, because the server time is at fault I believe. There's not much you can do except something really hacky just for this particular server, and that's a bad idea.

Comment: I currently  use www.2freehosting.com

Answer (score 0):

Daylight savings is not applied to GMT.  Try using Europe/London instead.

Comment: **Mon, 09/14/2015 01:21:11 am BST Europe/London**   adding 1 hour, it's not correct

Comment: Well, that IS odd.  Currently, Morocco & London have DST applied (+1 hour).  GMT SHOULD currently be one hour behind your local time.  Current time in New York SHOULD be **Sun, 09/13/2015 19:31:41 pm EDT America/New_York** Check that the free hosting server is correct.